# every vowel appearing three times regardless of the input

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char a[100];
    int c, e=0;
    char d;
    printf("enter a text of your choice\n");
    scanf("%s",a);
    printf("enter the vowel you want to know its occurence\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c",&d);
    for(c=0;c<strlen(a);c++)
    {
        if(a[c]=='a'||a[c]=='o'||a[c]=='e'||a[c]=='u'||a[c]=='i')
        e++;
    }
    printf("in the text ");
    for(c=0;c<strlen(a);c++)
        printf("%c",a[c]);
    printf("\nthe vowel%c",d);
    printf(" appears %d",e);
    printf(" times.\n");
    getch();
}
```

I am compiling and getting the wrong output that each and every vowel appears three times no matter the user input help.

Comment: So, your claim is that if the user enters 'bb' as the word, you get 3 vowels entered?  That seems improbable.  So, illustrate?  Your test counts all vowels, not just the one that the user specified, so if you enter words with three vowels, you will get 3 regardless.

Comment: Chances are working `d` somewhere into that loop of counting occurrences of the character held in `d` would probably be helpful.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour according to the standard, ditch it. Oh and a pedantic note: strictl**y** speaking, _y_ can be a vowel, too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read in the vowel in the variable `d` but then never make use of it, so you will get the counts of all vowels in your input text, provided there are no other bugs in the code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to match the entered vowel, Change

```
  if(a[c]=='a'||a[c]=='o'||a[c]=='e'||a[c]=='u'||a[c]=='i')
```

to

```
 if(a[c]==d)
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not compare the characters in your text "a" to the entered character 'd' at all! So just count the number of vowels in the loop, not the occurrences of a specific character...